# Sharpdx Direct3D10 How to edit pixels in texture?

Tags: texture2d, sharpdx, direct3d10

I need to change certain pixels in a texture (Texture2D) using Sharpdx with dx10

Right now I got

`Texture.Map(0, MapMode.Write, MapFlags.None, out stream);`

but I get a "The parameter is incorrect." exception.

All solutions I find are for either dx9 or dx11 or something other then Sharpdx and the used methods don't exist in Sharpdx.Direct3D10, hopefully someone here knows how to do this simple task of editing a texture...